# AWS S3 CreateReadStream in a loop only reads and writes 1 file

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3

I am trying to retrieve multiple files from S3 using a readstream, and insert them into a single file locally.

Below, the 'output' variable is the single writestream I wish to append to using the downloaded S3 file data.

I am looping through days where the nextDay variable is used for the S3 key. The fileservice.s3Handler.getS3Obj returns an S3 object which allows a readstream for a single file and appending to the output file.
However, no other files are being read and are not showing the console either using the on('data', ()) method. 
I tried to wrap the readstream in a promise to try to wait until the read was finished but it is running the same error.

More recently I keep get this error: `"ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END"`

Not sure what is going wrong here.

```
async fetchCSV(req, res) {

    const output = fs.createWriteStream(outputPathWithFile, {
                   'flags': 'a'});

    let nextDay = startDate;

    while (nextDay !== endDate) {

        const s3path = path.join(`${req.params.stationId}`, `${nextDay}.csv`);

        const file = await this.fileService.s3Handler.getS3Obj(s3path);

        await this.completePipe(file, output);

        nextDay = await getTomorrow(nextDay);
    }
```

}

```
completePipe(file, output) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        file.createReadStream().on('finish', () => {
            resolve();

        }).on('error', (err) => {
            resolve();

        }).on('data', (data) => {
            console.log(data.toString());

        }).pipe(output);
    })
}
```

}

```
getS3Obj(file) {

    return new Promise(async (resolve) => {

            const getParams = {
                Bucket: this.bucket,
                Key: file
            };
            resolve(this.s3.getObject(getParams, (err) => {

                if (err) {
                    console.log('Error in getS3 object')
                }
            }));


    })
}
```

Please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.

Did a couple things:

1. Added a tag to the pipe method.

   stream.pipe(output, {end: false})
2. Instead of creating a new function for the promise I just put this code in instead:

   ```
   await new Promise((resolve) => {
       stream.once('finish',  () => {
           resolve();
       });
   });
   ```

But the tag was what made it work, the promise was just a tidy up.

Yay.